# Why "Empty do" error when my do isn't empty?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a menu which gives output based on user input. However, I get a empty do error even though I have code for it to do underneath it. Am I missing something?

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
       contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
       let storage = (read contents :: [Spa])
       putStrLn "Please Enter Your Name: "
       name <- getLine
       putStrLn ""
       putStrLn ("Welcome " ++ name)
       menu storage
       putStrLn ""

       where menu resDB = do
                            putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
                            putStrLn "1: Add a new spa to the database "
                            putStrLn "2: Exit"                      
                            putStr "\nSelected option: "
                            putStrLn ""
                            option <- getLine    
                            output :: Int -> IO ()
                            output = do 
                                case option of
                                    1 -> putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
```

Comment: Please include the full error message. They are produced by the compiler for a reason.

Comment: is it because of the other do on top? but those don't show any error though.

Comment: Can you get please rid of that massive excess indentation? Convention is to have all top-level bindings flush to the left; remove all that whitespace. I don't see how this can be the cause of that particular problem, but indentation does often cause parse errors. Make it a habit to indent everything just as much as needed, and always use spaces, not tabs. (Your text editor/IDE should be able to handle that even if you use the TAB key, but you may need to configure it accordingly.)

Comment: @TitaniaLo maybe you missed argument `option` when defined function `output`

Comment: Sorry about the indentations but there is two more do operation on top. This is the third do for output which has issue. first one is to run the inserting of textfile, second is for menu and third one is the one which is the current one with issue.

Comment: If there's more on top and that's relevant for the parsing, then how are we supposed to analyse what's the cause of your parsing error? Always post [MCVE]s.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that since this is the portion with error, I didn't reveal the rest. Because some told me that we shouldn't give too much code which is confusing since the issue is on third do.

Comment: Indeed you shouldn't give _too much_ code, in particular all those `putStrLn` lines. But you should give _enough_ code. The way to go is to remove anything that seems unnecessary, but then paste your code snippet from the question draft back into a source file and try if it still has the behaviour you want.

Comment: I will improve! Thank you for teaching me.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed an indentation problem. Let me just give a version that parses correctly and is eye-friendly:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
  let storage = read contents :: [Spa]
  -- ...
  menu storage
 where menu resDB = do
         putStrLn "~~~" 
         putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
         putStrLn "1: Add a new spa to the database "
         -- ...
         option <- getLine    
         putStrLn "~~~"

         output option

       output :: Int -> IO ()
       output option = case option of
         1 -> putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
```

Note that `output` is indented only to the level of the `where` block, not the `do` block. Generally, `do` blocks are for writing *statements* (monadic actions), not for giving *declarations* like you tried here. You *can* always embed declarations in a `do` block, but you need to put them in a `let` block: this also works, and allows omitting `option` as an explicit argument to `output` because they're now inside the same local scope:

```
 where menu resDB = do
         putStrLn "~~~" 
         option <- getLine    

         let output :: IO ()
             output = case option of
               1 -> putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "

         output
```

But, if you're only defining `output` in order to immediately invoke it exactly once, then you might as well inline the declaration entirely:

```
 where menu resDB = do
         putStrLn "~~~" 
         option <- getLine    
         case option of
           1 -> putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
```

Depending on the amount of code, a named declaration does make sense though.

You can reduce the needed indentation even more: this style avoids the seven-space indented `where` block. I personally don't like it as much though.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
  let storage = read contents :: [Spa]
  -- ...
  menu storage
 where
  menu resDB = do
    putStrLn "~~~" 
    -- ...
```

And both `menu` and `output` could also be declared at the top-level (i.e. with no indentation at all), provided that you do use explicit arguments to pass around the data. Furthermore, you can use just different clauses for that case distinction in `output`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
  menu $ read storage

menu :: [Spa] -> IO ()
menu resDB = do
  putStrLn "~~~" 
  -- ...
  option <- getLine    
  output option

output :: Int -> IO ()
output 1 = putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
output 2 = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```hs
main :: IO()
main = do 
       contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
       let storage = (read contents :: [Spa])
       putStrLn "Please Enter Your Name: "
       name <- getLine
       putStrLn ""
       putStrLn ("Welcome " ++ name)
       menu storage
       putStrLn "" where
            menu resDB = do
                putStrLn "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" 
                putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
                putStrLn "1: Add a new spa to the database "
                putStrLn "2: Show all spas in the database"
                putStrLn "3: Give all spas operating in a certain area"
                putStrLn "4: Give all spas that have a performance of 8 or higher "
                putStrLn "5: Give the average performance for the spas in a certain area "
                putStrLn "6: Give the names of the spas a given supervisor has rated the service level, along with that rating result for each spa."
                putStrLn "7: Give the names of the spas a given supervisor has yet to rate the service level, along with that spa performance."
                putStrLn "8: Allow a given chef rating to be entered (or updated) for a restaurant he has rated (note that only the latest result from the supervsior should remain recorded)"
                putStrLn "9: Exit"                      
                putStr "\nSelected option: "
                putStrLn ""
                option <- getLine    
                putStrLn "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

            output :: Int -> IO ()
            output option = do 
                case option of
                    1 -> putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
```

Comment: Where is variable `option` defined ? Should not we have something like  `output option = do ...`  ?

Comment: @jpmarinier yes, thank you, I wrote about this in comment in question, but forgot fix here)

Comment: I just updated the code but it still show the parse error on '='? I updated the question to show the position

Comment: @TitaniaLo Definition of function `output` was in block `do ...` in function `menu`, and this got error. You can wrote either as in my answer or add `where` after `putStrLn "~~~...`

Comment: They say the option for case 'option' of is variable not in scope as well couldn't match expected type 'Int -> IO()' with actual type 'IO()'.

Comment: @TitaniaLo I'm sorry, I forgot write `option` just after `output`

Answer (score 0):

The statements in a `do` block must be indented further than the  start of the line containing the `do`. But you have other problems too, like using a `let`, which does not make sense here.

Comment: I know about that but without the let, it became parse error on input '='. I have edited the code accordingly