# Menu option issue

Tags: haskell

I have editing this code for hours just trying to get rid of this indentation problem and I followed the link I did previously. But because I follow those code I need to readjust again because my spaDatabase and updatedDB is not being recognised which I end up need to readjust everything from the top again and now the bottom part part has problem AGAIN.

I keep deleting and adding space but the error is still there. I also try based on one of the recommended answer I get this parse error below. But if I remove it, it end up being second parse error.

```
let output :: IO ()
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

--second error
parse error on input `='
```

[Why "Empty do" error when my do isn't empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048507/why-empty-do-error-when-my-do-isnt-empty)

```
parse error on input `='

--line of error
output option = case option of
```

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
       contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
       let spaDatabase = (read contents :: [Spa])
       putStrLn "Please Enter Your Name: "
       name <- getLine
       putStrLn ("Welcome " ++ name)
       putStrLn ""
                let menu spaDatabase = do
                          putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
                          putStrLn "1: Add a new spa to the database "
                          option <- getLine

                
                                output :: IO ()
                                output option = case option of 
                                       1 -> do putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
                                               rid <- getLine
                                               let updatedDB = (addSpa rid br ar (read st) spaDatabase)
                                               putStrLn (spaListStr updatedDB)
                                           

                                       2 ->    putStrLn (spaListStr updatedDB) >> menu spaDB
                    
                                       3 -> do putStrLn "Enter Spa Area:"
                                               ar <- getLine
                                               putStrLn (spaListStr (read ar) spaDatabase)
```

Comment: This type signature: `output :: IO ()` tells us that `output` has no parameters, and the line just below tells us that it has exactly **one** parameter.

Comment: as in option 1 are you referring to?

Comment: This isn't making sense. In Haskell you use indentation like curly brackets in other languages (which is why I said to get rid of your curly brackets: having both confuses things).  Your extra indentation for the second "let"  and the "output" function is wrong. The "let" should be level with the "putStrLn" and "output" should be level with "menu"

Comment: @TitianaLo - it is not about any specific numeric value for `option`. The type you need for `output` is probably  `output :: Int -> IO ()`

Comment: @TitianaLo - Besides, if indenting with 8 spaces obviously makes your code unreadable (because it makes for very long lines and forces the reader to use the horizontal slider) you can consider indenting with just 4 spaces instead.

Comment: Honestly, I can't see that you at all followed the advice I gave in my answer to the other question. Read it again, make sure you _understand_ it. If you have concrete questions to details, you can ask about those, but not just slap all of your incrementally changed code again and again into questions. Closing this as duplicate.

Comment: If you keep having trouble with indentation, you can always use explicit curly braces `{` … `}` around blocks and semicolons `;` to separate items within a block. E.g. `do { a <- b; let { c = d; e f = g }; case h of { 1 -> do { … }; 2 -> do { … } } }`. Indentation is *syntactic sugar* for explicit delimiters like that. Alternatively, you can follow the rule “after a block keyword such as `do`, `let`, `where`, or `of`, insert a newline and indent by a fixed number of spaces”, which should always produce correct indentation. (The compiler may still *mention* indentation for other syntax errors.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is with the indents fixed. It's still not right: it defines `menu` and `output` but doesn't call them. But it should at least get you past the syntax errors.

```
main :: IO()
main = do 
       contents <- readFile "spa.txt"
       let spaDatabase = (read contents :: [Spa])
       putStrLn "Please Enter Your Name: "
       name <- getLine
       putStrLn ("Welcome " ++ name)
       putStrLn ""
       
menu spaDatabase = do
             putStrLn "\nPlease select an option:"
             putStrLn "1: Add a new spa to the database "
             getLine  -- This returns the value, so no need for <-
 
output :: Int -> IO ()
output option = case option of 
             1 -> do 
                putStrLn "Enter Spa ID: "
                rid <- getLine
                let updatedDB = (addSpa rid br ar (read st) spaDatabase)
                putStrLn (spaListStr updatedDB)                           

             2 -> putStrLn (spaListStr updatedDB) >> menu spaDB
  
             3 -> do 
                putStrLn "Enter Spa Area:"
                ar <- getLine
                putStrLn (spaListStr (read ar) spaDatabase)
```